# Is it possible to combine two textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, image, color

So I made these fenders for a truck and added a picture as material, the flames and red color are both from the same picture but I think it looks kinda boring (It's a big png with an entire colorscheme for other parts as well).

I was thinking about making/downloading an aluminium material and combine the picture and aluminium to give it that shiny look like a real truck. Not sure how I need to do this so any help would be awesome!

edit: here's the link to the image: https://ibb.co/Twc7W9Z 
The colors look cool but I wanna give those  parts a material look as well, like chrome, aluminium, etc..

[image]

edit 2: 
It is now like this:[image: now]

and I wanna make it look like real material and shine like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the flame texture?

Comment: I can't because the image file is over 2mb so I can't upload it. As I said, it contains textures for wheels, doors, etc.. as well.

Comment: I added a link so take a look if u can open that

Comment: Like this? https://prnt.sc/xyz9nl

Comment: I added some more pictures, maybe u understand what I mean now

Comment: You don't need to mix textures, you just need to increase clearcoat in your Principled BSDF shader, as well as tweak other settings (set metaliness to 1, roughness to low), and add proper lightning (perhaps some HDRI which is crucial for reflections).

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I just experimented a bit with all these settings and it already looks a lot better! I was going to add scuffed metal and things like that, can I still add these scratches, etc.. on top of that texture?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can in many ways. You can just mix RGB:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Or similarly you can mix shaders (here the effect is the same, but with different Principled BSDF settings it would differ):

[image: 3]

Or you can do something more interesting:

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

If you have some specific textures in mind and a specific way to merge them, it would be good if you described them in your question. A texture with scratches could be added based on it's alpha channel for example.